# Corresponding a button with an array slot

Tags: objective-c

I want to put a bunch of buttons on the screen that correspond with an array slot.
For example, buttonA corresponds to myArray[3][28].

Would I have to have a ton of else-if statements like this:

```
else if (x == 3 && y == 28)
    //"it's buttonQ" code
else if (x == 3 && y == 29)
    //"it's buttonR" code
```

or is there a better way?

Note: x is the "horizontal" index of the 2D array myArray, while y is its "vertical" index

Comment: could you provide a little more detail as to how buttonA corresponds to myArray[3][28]? What are x and y?

Comment: Sorry about that. X is the "horizontal" index of the array, while y is its "vertical" index

Answer (score 0):

I think it is feasible to devise a scheme where you can use the position as part of your data scheme. It seems to me that this is what you are doing anyway because you are relating the horizontal coordinates to letters in the alphabet.

So you could do for example something like this:

```
NSString *letters = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ";

...
else if (x == 3) {
   NSString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c"
                             [letters characterAtIndex:y-11]];
   // use letter in your code
}
...
```

Similarly, you could device code that takes into account the row as well in a more complex matrix of buttons.